# AppStore submission - how to duplicate the release configuration?

Tags: app-store, submission, build-settings

I'm in the throes of attempting to submit an app via XCode 4. I've just noticed, per this url from Apple :

```
http://tinyurl.com/3ol2qoj
```

that to prepare an app for submission to the app store in XCode 4, you must:

1. In your project, duplicate the Release build configuration and name the duplicate “AppStore”.
2. Set the Code Signing Identity build setting to your team’s distribution code signing identity through the application’s distribution provisioning profile for the AppStore build configuration.

The page shows an image (which I'd post if I knew how) which has the project highlighted (not the targets). The BuildSettings, Code Signing Identity for the project shows an AppStore entry above the Debug and Release entries.

My questions is, what is the method for duplicating that release entry?

Comment: project, info, configurations and duplicate

Answer (score 61):

You need to go to the `Info` tab located in the Project settings (not the target apps). You'll see a list of configurations there (Debug, Release). Click on the + at the bottom and then Duplicate "Release" Configuration

Comment: make sure the entry below the "Project" node is selected rather than the Targets entry...